# Remove whitespace around an enumeration in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, enumerate, enumitem

I've tried using the `enumitem` suggestion given on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968557/latex-very-compact-itemize, but I still see white space around my enumeration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lp{.7\textwidth}}
1 & \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
\item \lipsum[2]{}
\item \lipsum[3]{}
\end{enumerate}\\
2 & \lipsum[5]{}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I found a `compress` trick in one of the answers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum,array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\compress}p{.7\textwidth}}
1 & \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
\item \lipsum[2]{}
\item \lipsum[3]{}
\end{enumerate}\\
2 & \lipsum[5]{}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This gets rid of the white space above the list, but the one on the bottom still remains:

[image]

The end result is that the table looks unbalanced — when some of the rows **are not** an enumeration, there is no spacing between them. When a row **is** an enumeration, there is spacing.

How can I get rid of the extra white space below an enumeration?

Comment: And what is your question now? Or is it just a remark?

Comment: My question is how to get rid of the extra white space at the bottom of an enumeration. I'll copy it from the title to the text, sorry.

Comment: I don't understand why you enumeration is inside a tabular environment?

Comment: @Bernard The use case is that I have some classification and criteria for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum,array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{nosep,label=\arabic*.,after*=\vspace{-\baselineskip}} %% adjust \vspace as needed.

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\compress}p{.7\textwidth}}
1 & \begin{myenumerate}
       \item \lipsum[2]
       \item \lipsum[3]
    \end{myenumerate}\\
2 & \lipsum[5]{}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But......

Are you sure you want to do this *this way*. Here there can't be page breaks.

As an alternative, you can use a list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum,array}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label=\arabic*.,after*=\vspace{-0.25\baselineskip}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*]
\item
     \begin{myenumerate}
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[3]
    \end{myenumerate}
\item \lipsum[5]{}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The data is tabular, so unfortunately I can't use a list. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @ipavlic Glad it helped. :)