# Vertical alignment to top in longtable

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I have the following schematic code:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[t]{p{0.10\linewidth}| p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.20\linewidth}}
\hline
{\bf Country} & {\bf Column 1} & {\bf Column 2} & {\bf Column 3} & {\bf Column 4} \\ \hline
Brazil & 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt,label={\arabic*)}]
\item  x
\item  y
\item z
\end{enumerate} & 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, label={\arabic*)}]
\item  x 
\item  y 
\item  z
\end{enumerate} & 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, label=]
\item  a
\item b
\item c
\item d
\end{enumerate} & 
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, label=]
\item  a
\item b
\end{enumerate} \\ \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Which gives the following output:
[image]

I would like all the cells to be aligned to the top, i.e., be on the same line as "Brazil". I thought that using "{p{0.10\linewidth}| p{0.20\linewidth} ...." would take care of that, but it doesn't. Does someone have an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: please always supply a small but complete test file, also unrelated but `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993. The `enumitem` package (which you appear to be using, although you have not said)  provides list options that avoid the top spacing to give more compact lists in tables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will add the usepackages. Based on your comment I included "topsep=0pt" in the enumerates but then still "Brazil" and the lists are not on the same vertical level.

Comment: try noitemsep option or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184526/remove-whitespace-around-an-enumeration-in-a-table

Comment: You may be interested in [this older answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593565/134144) to a similar question.

Comment: Any news? How you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}       % for nice list
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\setlist{nosep=0pt,
         leftmargin=*,
         after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
         before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
         }
%
    \begin{longtable}{p{0.10\linewidth}| p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.20\linewidth} p{0.20\linewidth}}
\hline
\textbf{Country} & \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} & \textbf{Column 4} \\ \hline
Brazil &
\begin{enumerate}
\item  x
\item  y
\item z
\end{enumerate} &
\begin{enumerate}
\item  x
\item  y
\item  z
\end{enumerate} &
\begin{enumerate}[label=]
\item a
\item b
\item c
\item d
\end{enumerate} &
\begin{enumerate}
\item  a
\item b
\end{enumerate} \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]